# C# - pass on variable amount of parameters to other method within a method

Tags: c#, variables, dynamic, parameters, overloading

I know the title is a little bit tricky to understand, but the following example should clarify what I mean:

Imagine you have a method with 2 overloads:

```
void Method(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Method(int) called");
}

void Method(int i, string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Method(int, string) called");
}
```

Then you have another method that takes a variable amount of parameters:

```
void MethodOverload(params dynamic[] parameters)
{
    Method(parameters); // Call one of the overloading methods depending on the parameter amount and their type 
}
```

The method above accepts any amount of parameters with any type. I want to call one of the overloading methods depending on the amount of passed parameters and their type.

For example:

```
void Run()
{
    TestFuncOverload(5);                 // Output: "testFunc(int) called"
    TestFuncOverload(5, "some text");    // Output: "testFunc(int, string) called"

    TestFuncOverload(5, 5);              //Error
}
```

How does one achieve this in C#?

Comment: How about `if (parameters.Length == 1 && parameters[0] is int)
                Method(parameters[0]);

            if (parameters.Length == 2 && parameters[0] is int && parameters[1] is string)
                Method(parameters[0], parameters[1]);` i don't see another solution.

Comment: Well yes, but this is a simplified example. I don't want to create dozens of if statements for all types of parameters and all numbers of overloads for each function each time I need something like this in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I could do that with below code. It costs tons of reflection, you can consider another approach to avoid performance problems.

```
public class Test
{
    private void Method(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method(int) called");
    }
    private void Method(int i, string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method(int, string) called");
    }
    public void Method(params object[] parameters)
    {
        var m = typeof(Test).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                                .Where(x => x.Name == "Method" &&
                                           !x.GetParameters()
                                             .Any(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(ParamArrayAttribute), false)))
                                .Where(x => x.GetParameters().Count() == parameters.Count())
                                .Where(x => x.GetParameters()
                                             .Select(y => Type.GetType("System." + y.ParameterType.Name))
                                             .Zip(parameters.Select(z => z.GetType()), Equals)
                                             .All(q => q))
                                .FirstOrDefault();

        if(m == null) throw new Exception ("method not found");

        //null result because of void method.
        var result = m.Invoke(this, parameters);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
      Test t = new Test();
      //"Method(int) called"
      t.Method(0);
      //"Method(int, string) called"
      t.Method(0, "");
      //throws ex 
      t.Method("", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) but I don't recommend it. Reflection is slow and to do this you need to use it a lot. You should try to solve it with a different approach, but in case you **really** need to do it this way, this should do the trick:

```
    public void MethodOverload(params dynamic[] parameters)
    {
        //Check if the array is null
        if (parameters == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameters));

        //Create a list of the types in the dynamic[]
        var inputParameterTypes = new Type[parameters.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            inputParameterTypes[i] = parameters[i].GetType();
        }

        const string NameOfMethod = nameof(Method); //This should be the name of your method which will be called

        //Get every method from this class which has the name you are looking for
        var methods = this.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Where(x => x.Name == NameOfMethod);

        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            //Get the parameters of the method
            var methodParameters = method.GetParameters();

            if (methodParameters.Length != inputParameterTypes.Length)
                continue;

            //Check if the types match with the input parameters
            var match = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < methodParameters.Length; i++)
            {
                //Check if the type matches
                if (methodParameters[i].ParameterType == inputParameterTypes[i])
                    continue;

                //Doesn't match
                match = false;
            }
            if (!match)
                continue;

            //Call the method and return
            method.Invoke(this, parameters);
            return;
        }


        //If this is reached no valid methods were found
        throw new Exception("No valid methods found!");
    }
```

(This code assumes that all methods are in the same class)

After doing some measurements with this code:

```
        var a = new Foo();

        var parameters = new dynamic[][] 
            { 
                new dynamic[] { 1, "Test" }, 
                new dynamic[] { 2 } 
            };

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++)
        {
            a.MethodOverload(parameters[i % 2]);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"{Num} iterations took {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds} milliseconds. Average time: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / Num} milliseconds");
```

(Removed the Console.WriteLine from the called functions)

here are the results:

```
10000000 iterations took 5283.9398 milliseconds. Average time: 0.00052839398 milliseconds
100000000 iterations took 51244.9142 milliseconds. Average time: 0.000512449142 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) and call the method by [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=netcore-3.1).